# How does the definition of compactness imply that all continuous operators are compact in finite dimensional spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $S \subset X, Y$ be normed spaces over $K$. An operator $A:S \to
> Y$ is called compact if:
>
> 1. $A$ is continuous
> 2. $A$ transforms bounded set into relatively
>      compact sets i.e. if $(c_n)$ is a bounded
>      sequence in $\mathbb{S}$, $\exists (c_n') \subset (c_n)$ s.t.
>      $(Ac_n')$ is convergent in Y

Why should it be obvious that all continuous operators $A$ in finite dimensional space i.e. $R^n$ are compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer this in several ways, drawing upon the mainstream structural results in finite-dim. spaces, e.g. the Bolzano-Weierstrass property that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, and then noting that continuous operators preserve sequential convergence.